# Publication posts after admin approving in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, state-machine

How to do that posts will publish only after admin appriving in Ruby on Rails app using (State_machine or Workflow)?

Comment: do you really need state_machine or workflow for that ?

Comment: add column 'approved' to your Post model and create admin interface. State machine probably need you, if you are would send emails to admin with message about new posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with `state_machine` or `workflow` gems, since you have very few states and behaviours tied to them.

Those gems are more for running code based of very many states.

Just take a look at the `Vehicle` example in the `state_mahcine` docs.

https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine#example

I've achieved what you're trying to do before by simply using an `enum`.

Add an `enum` to your model called `status`.

```
enum status: [:draft, :review, :published]
```

You will need to add an `integer` column called `status` to your postings.

```
add_column :posts, :status, :integer, default: 0, null: false
```

Now wherever you are showing the posts simply query out the unpublished posts.

```
@posts = Post.published
```

I added the statuses `:draft`, `:review` and `:published`, but you could have as few or many enums.